# Is my proof correct? m×n complex matrix A*A is invertible iff A has full column rank.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a high school student in South Korea. I am currently learning Linear Algebra in school. In this question, $A^*$ means conjugate transpose.
I am wondering if this sentence is true or false. [m×n complex matrix $A^*A$ is invertible iff $A$ has full column rank.]
If A is real, it is true and the proof is simple. Since $null(A^{T}A)=null(A)$, $rank(A^{T}A)=rank(A)$ so $A^{T}A$ is invertible iff A has full column rank.
Is it okay if I use this result directly in complex field?(Assuming standard inner product in a complex field, $A^*Ax=0 \implies x ^* A ^* Ax=0,||Ax||^{2}=0\,\,Ax=0$ so $A ^* A$ and $A$ has the same nullspace, and so on. ) Or if there is a counterexample, please tell me. $%(I don't know why the conjugate transpose expression is not working with mathjax in my computer.. sorry)$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A is m×n complex matrix, A*A is invertible iff A has full column rank, is it true or false?

Comment: Note that $A^*A$ is always square, even if $A$ is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the statement holds and the idea behind your proof is correct. Here is one complete version of the proof.

If $A^*A$ is invertible, then
$$
Ax = 0 \implies A^*Ax = 0 \implies (A^*A)^{-1}(A^*A)x = 0 \implies x = 0,
$$
which means that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, which means that $A$ has full column rank.

Conversely, if $A$ has full column rank, then we find that
$$
A^*Ax = 0 \implies x^*A^*Ax = 0 \implies (Ax)^*(Ax) = 0 
\\\implies \|Ax\|^2 = 0 \implies Ax = 0 \implies x = 0.
$$
Thus, $A^*A$ is a square matrix with linearly independent columns, which means that $A^*A$ is invertible.